# How does one display search results for multiple vectors? C++

Tags: c++, search, vector

Let's assume that a user search for some number in a vector ( vector  numbers();), how does one display a result from that vector[i] with corresponding [i] in other vectors?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Are you trying to check the element at index i against the element at index i in multiple other vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) for this.

#### Example Code

```
for(yourVector<YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE>::iterator it = yourVector.begin(); it != yourVector.end(); it++)
    if(it == indexOfDesiredElement) {
         YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE theValue = *it;
         // pass theValue to a helper method and proceed from there.
}
}
```